# Assign a Class Dynamically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Is it possible to assign a class to an object in code? I am creating a button dynamically, loading an image for the button, and I have something like the following:

```
myButton = [[[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(100,100,50,25)] autorelease];
[myButton setTitle:@"Done"];
[myButton setTarget:self];
[myButton setAction:@selector(mySelector:)];
[myButton setButtonType:NSMomentaryChangeButton];
[myButton setBordered:NO];
[myButton setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"myButton.png"]];
[myButton setImagePosition: NSImageOnly];
[[[self window] contentView] addSubview:myButton];
```

I also have an NSButton subclass (e.g. MyButtonClass.h/MyButtonClass.m) that I want to use for the button so that it has a particular behavior, but I'm not sure how to assign that class to the button in the above code.

Is this possible, or can/should it be done only in Interface Builder?

Comment: You mean that you want `myButton` to be an instance of your custom class instead of a "generic" `NSButton`? Just use `MyButtonClass` instead of `NSButton` when you create it...

Comment: Thanks Josh, three answers within a minute which I guess betrays my total newb status. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initiate your button with `MyButtonClass` instead of `NSButton`

`myButton = [[[MyButtonClass alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(100,100,50,25)] autorelease];`

Comment: Boy that was embarrassingly easy, thanks Zen!

Comment: Everything starts at some point or other. So keep learning and happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

When you create the button, don't create them as NSButtons, create them as your subclass. For example, if you had a subclass of NSButton called MyButton, instead of something like:

```
NSButton *button = [[[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame]autorelease];
```

You would have something like:

```
MyButton *button = [[[MyButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame]autorelease];
```

This way button will be an instance of MyButton.

Comment: Hi navinsillu, zen pipped you by one minute but the thanks goes to you as well. :)